# 'gem install ffi' failed on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, rubygems

I'm trying to set up a RoR environment under RVM on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 on my macbook pro.
The ruby version that I need to install is 1.9.3-p194 because it's required for my software development project.

So far, I have the following software installed on my Macbook:

```
RVM
ruby 1.9.3-p194
xcode v6.4 and the respective version of command line tools
Mac OS X version: 10.10.5 Yosemite
```

It seems I'm running into a problem that the ffi gem (an independency of my project) cannot be built successfully.

I get the following error whenever I try to install the gem via the command "gem install ffi -v '1.9.3'"

```
MacBook-Pro:demo-project apple$ gem install ffi -v '1.9.3'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160428-1898-idt325.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi_call() in -lffi... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-ffilib
    --without-ffilib
/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:845:in `block in have_library'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:840:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:20:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/ffi-1.9.3/gem_make.out
```

I said I have the xcode command line tools installed, but notice from the given error below that it gave me a hint "You have to install development tools first".

Didn't I have it installed already? I was asking myself out of curiousity.
Then I googled and found out the way how to check if I have xcode command line tools installed. Then I launched the terminal and issued that command as illustrated below, and the result did confirm that the piece of software was already installed.

```
MacBook-Pro:demo-project apple$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Here is also my gcc version:

```
MacBook-Pro:demo-project apple$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

I have searched all over the web and tried many solutions, but, unfortunately, without success.
Any advice would be very much appreciated to get this to work.

**Updated:**

My mkmf.log

```
package configuration for libffi
cflags: -I/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include
ldflags: -L/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib
libs: -lffi

"/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 -o conftest -I/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin14.5.0 -I/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -I/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/libffi-3.0.13/include conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L. -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib     -lffi -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

Comment: what do show the `mkmf.log`?

Comment: Thanks Малъ. I have updated my question putting the mkmf.log in there.
It seems like it's referencing the wrong gcc compiler version, the gcc-4.9?
It's a bit complicated, let me explain on. The gcc version that was originally shipped with Yosemite is gcc v.4.2. It didn't seem to work at first, then I tried to install gcc-4.9. And after that experimental attempt, I last minute decided to remove the gcc-4.9 anyway.
Surprisingly, it's still looking for gcc-4.9 here even if it was removed. (Currently, if I run gcc -v, it shows gcc 4.2 now) I still got no idea what to do though.

Comment: have you gcc4-9? and I didn't see the errcode, did you missed it?

Comment: The fact is I removed it already, gcc-4.9, from my machine, but I only notice it's still referenced as in the mkmf.log you previously asked me to paste in the question above
"/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9 -o conftest -I/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin14.5.0  blah blah blah .....

Comment: well define in bash path to  `export GCC=gcc-4.2`, then issue installation of the gem

Comment: ah, thanks. I will give it a try. ;-)